# Is a complex scalar multiple of an eigenvector also an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So suppose $A\mathbf{v}=\lambda\mathbf{v}$ where $A$ is a square matrix, $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda$ is a corresponding eigenvalue.
To my knowledge, all $c_i\mathbf{v}_i$, where $c_i\in\Bbb{R}$ , is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=\lambda_i$.
My question is, suppose $k_i\in\Bbb{C}$ , is $k_i\mathbf{v}_i$ also an eigenvector?

Comment: This is a bit nuanced. If $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\lambda v$ only makes sense if $\lambda$ is real-valued (otherwise you break closure with scalar multiplication). If $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$, then yes $\lambda v$ will be an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**
If $c \in \mathbb C$ and $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ (recall that eigenvalues can be complex), then
$$ A(c \mathbf v) = c A \mathbf v = c \lambda \mathbf v = \lambda (c \mathbf v). $$